# Train a text model to predict true or false

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, keras, caffe

So I am new to the whole machine learning topic but I think I have an interesting problem to solve. I basically just want to know if a sentence conforms to *TRUE* or *FALSE*

Here a some sample sentences:

- Yes this is me -> TRUE
- This was me -> TRUE
- Yes true -> TRUE
- This was not me -> FALSE

....

Now I would need some hints how I can successfully train a model in e.g. Keras, Caffe or other tools and what kind of principal I should follow.

Thanks for any hints

**Update**

So from what I understood I need to do natural language classification. I would need to create 2 classes and get the probability for each of the classes back.

Could something like https://github.com/Russell91/nlpcaffe be useful?

Comment: This is too broad. What have you looked into so far? Where specifically do you have a programming related problem?

Comment: I tried to improve the question

Comment: I suggest you give way more specific information about your use case and more context about your existing knowledge regarding machine learning / deeplearning and NLP. What exactly do you try to achieve by this classification? How many samples do you have? Have you tried shallow learning approaches like Bag of Words, tfidf, Naive Bayes etc.? Have you  looked into word embeddings, Word2Vec, RNN, LSTMs? Or do you start from the very beginning? If the latter – start here: http://course.fast.ai/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, you want to categorize various kinds of responses into `true`/`false`, which are perhaps responses to questions as part of a conversation.

For this scenario, you should be creating/having a dataset with a large number of examples for both `true` and `false` classes and train a binary text classifier. You can read up on SVM and Naive Bayes which are very good for text classification and easily implementable using Scikit-Learn.